# Assigning Javascript click callbacks to Flash elements?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

Bear in mind I'm a web developer but not a Flash developer and know little about Flash. I work with people who are the opposite and know very little about web development. Maybe someone who is good with both can answer this question?

I work for an Advertisement software company and we are having fits with our Ad click-throughs opening tabs vs popups in different browsers. Tabs are preferred becaus pop-ups are subject to blockers.

I read that tabs will always be opened if it is a callback triggered by a user click. This is fine with me.

Problem is the Flash developers, using their external interface, are trying to open the new window when the Flash ad gets clicked themselves. So even though it's user initiated Flash behooves upon itself to open the website. I think this may be why they end up being popups instead of new tabs.

Is there a way external to Flash using Javascript to assign the click events to Flash elements so that only new tabs will ever be opened by clicking the Flash element? Or a way through Flash can assign Javascript callbacks to its elements? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [navigateToURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) from Adobe's API Reference, and you will notice the second (oft ommitted) argument is the window to open it in.

> "If you do not specify a value for this parameter, a new empty window is created." *- Adobe*

I believe `"_blank"` should create a new tab.  In AS3, it'd look like this:

`navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.apple.com"), "_blank");`